# Clear of vector is not happening in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, angular

I have a screen where I have a button 'A' on click of which a popup opens. In that popup, I have a map which consist a vector layer (Polygon). I have another button 'Remove Shape' in that popup. Now when I click that Remove Shape button, I am able to remove the vector layer from the map by using

```
this.map.getLayers()"array_".getSource().clear();
```

Although, the layer (Shape Polygon) is getting removed, on closing the popup and reopening it, I can't remove the shape again.

Can any one help me with this and let me know if I am missing anything anywhere ?

[image: Popup Screenshot]

Comment: How are you adding layers and features?  If you have two layers, to clear features from the top layer you would use
`this.map.getLayers().getArray()[1].getSource().clear();`  It does not remove the layer.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more of relevant code.